# Why does R exclude values of 1 when calculating a mean using the aggregate function?

Tags: r

I have a series of different columns in my dataset that I am trying to use the aggregate command on in order to determine the number of observations, mean and sd for each individual in my study. I then want to determine the mean and sd across all individuals. The problem I am encountering is that for the first aggregate command all is fine but for the second, the mean command is excluding any mean values from the first aggregate that were calculated using a single number. I have made an example data frame below to try to illustrate my problem.

Firstly here is the sample dataset:

```
    structure(list(groupnumber = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), tagnumber = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), disturbance = c("Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), sleepstate = c("WAKE", "SWS", 
    "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", 
    "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", 
    "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", 
    "REM", "WAKE", "SWS", "REM"), proportion = c(0.25, 0.33, 0.42, 
    0.18, 0.44, 0.38, 0.11, 0.19, 0.7, 0.55, 0.17, 0.28, 0.42, 0.22, 
    0.36, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.42, 0.31, 0.27, 0.21, 0.38, 0.41, 0.65, 
    0.2, 0.15, 0.11, 0.52, 0.37, 0.28, 0.39, 0.33)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -33L))
```

Then I run the first aggregate as follows:

```
    troubletablelong<-as.data.frame(aggregate(cbind(trouble$proportion)~trouble$tagnumber+trouble$disturbance+trouble$sleepstate,data=trouble,FUN=function(x)c(nobs(x),mean(x),sd(x))))
```

Resulting in:

```
    structure(list(`trouble$tagnumber` = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L), `trouble$disturbance` = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), `trouble$sleepstate` = c("REM", "REM", "REM", 
    "SWS", "SWS", "SWS", "WAKE", "WAKE", "WAKE"), V1 = structure(c(5, 
    5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 0.428, 0.28, 0.33, 0.27, 0.322, 0.39, 
    0.302, 0.398, 0.28, 0.160374561573836, 0.11, NA, 0.113357840487546, 
    0.134610549363711, NA, 0.180194339533738, 0.236156727619604, 
    NA), dim = c(9L, 3L))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

And with a tiny bit of clean-up and column headings:

```
    structure(list(tagnumber = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L), disturbance = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
    "Y"), sleepstate = c("REM", "REM", "REM", "SWS", "SWS", "SWS", 
    "WAKE", "WAKE", "WAKE"), nobs = c(5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1), 
    mean = c(0.428, 0.28, 0.33, 0.27, 0.322, 0.39, 0.302, 0.398, 
        0.28), sd = c(0.160374561573836, 0.11, NA, 0.113357840487546, 
        0.134610549363711, NA, 0.180194339533738, 0.236156727619604, 
        NA)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Of note here is the fact that the number of observations for tagnumber 3 for each sleep state is only 1. This results in a mean value calculated using only a single value and of course no sd can be calculated hence the 3 NAs in the last column.

I then want to run another aggregate function exactly the same as the first but across all tag numbers so that I only get a single value for each of the 3 sleep states. The code for that is as follows:

```
    newtroubletablelong2<-as.data.frame(aggregate(cbind(newtroubletablelong$mean,newtroubletablelong$sd)~newtroubletablelong$sleepstate+newtroubletablelong$disturbance,data=newtroubletablelong,FUN=function(x) c(nobs(x),mean(x),sd(x))))
```

Resulting in:

```
    structure(list(`newtroubletablelong$sleepstate` = c("REM", "SWS", 
    "WAKE"), `newtroubletablelong$disturbance` = c("Y", "Y", "Y"), 
        V1 = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 0.354, 0.296, 0.35, 0.104651803615609, 
        0.0367695526217005, 0.0678822509939086), dim = c(3L, 3L)), 
        V2 = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 0.135187280786918, 0.123984194925629, 
        0.208175533576671, 0.0356201940881585, 0.0150279345649194, 
        0.0395713841069094), dim = c(3L, 3L))), row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Again with some clean-up and column headings we get:

```
    structure(list(sleepstate = c("REM", "SWS", "WAKE"), disturbance = c("Y", 
    "Y", "Y"), meannobs = c(2, 2, 2), meanmean = c(0.354, 0.296, 
    0.35), meansd = c(0.104651803615609, 0.0367695526217005, 0.0678822509939086
    ), sdnobs = c(2, 2, 2), sdmean = c(0.135187280786918, 0.123984194925629, 
    0.208175533576671), sdsd = c(0.0356201940881585, 0.0150279345649194, 
    0.0395713841069094)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Unfortunately the number of observations used here is only 2 when it should be 3 as per the previous table and I am unsure why R is omitting this value for this second mean calculation. If anyone could tell me why this is happening and how I could tweak my code to prevent this it would be greatly appreciated. And apologies for any formatting issues as this is my first post!

Comment: Just to point iout, since you are using `data = trouble, you dio not need the `$` part. ie run `aggregate(proportion~tagnumber+disturbance+sleepstate,data=trouble,FUN=function(x)c(length(x),mean(x),sd(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler way. Two `aggregate` will do it.

Notice `na.action = na.pass`, the default is `na.omit`. And since in the second `aggregate` 1 in 3 values of `sd` are `NA`'s, with the default setting only two values are passed on to the aggregation function.

```r
agg <- aggregate(proportion ~ ., trouble[-1], \(x) {
  c(nobs = length(x), mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
}, na.action = na.pass)
agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])
agg
#>   tagnumber disturbance sleepstate nobs  mean        sd
#> 1         1           Y        REM    5 0.428 0.1603746
#> 2         2           Y        REM    5 0.280 0.1100000
#> 3         3           Y        REM    1 0.330        NA
#> 4         1           Y        SWS    5 0.270 0.1133578
#> 5         2           Y        SWS    5 0.322 0.1346105
#> 6         3           Y        SWS    1 0.390        NA
#> 7         1           Y       WAKE    5 0.302 0.1801943
#> 8         2           Y       WAKE    5 0.398 0.2361567
#> 9         3           Y       WAKE    1 0.280        NA


agg2 <- aggregate(cbind(nobs, mean, sd) ~ ., agg[-1], \(x) {
  c(meannobs = length(x), meanmean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), meansd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}, na.action = na.pass)
agg2 <- cbind(agg2[1:2], agg2[[4]], agg2[[5]])
names(agg2)[6:8] <- sub("^mean", "sd", names(agg2)[6:8])
agg2
#>   disturbance sleepstate meannobs  meanmean     meansd sdnobs    sdmean
#> 1           Y        REM        3 0.3460000 0.07528612      3 0.1351873
#> 2           Y        SWS        3 0.3273333 0.06017752      3 0.1239842
#> 3           Y       WAKE        3 0.3266667 0.06274817      3 0.2081755
#>         sdsd
#> 1 0.03562019
#> 2 0.01502793
#> 3 0.03957138
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rui, but I noticed that my problem persists even within your code. Your second aggregate table also only uses 2 of 3 numbers to calculate the mean. Do you have any idea why this is or how to fix it?

Comment: @e_putyora Done, see the edit.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I hate to be a pain but would you be able to briefly explain what I had wrong in my code that resulted in the error in the first place? I feel like this would be a good learning opportunity for me.

Comment: @e_putyora 1) If you use the data argument, as you should, don't use `trouble$` ever; 2) Don't `cbind` just one column, the 2nd `cbind` is OK; 3) `aggregate` returns a data.frame, do not do `as.data.frame(aggregate(.))`.